# Optimizing compression using HDF5/H5 in Matlab

Tags: matlab, compression, hdf5

Using Matlab, I am going to generate several data files and store them in H5 format as `20x1500xN`, where N is an integer that can vary, but typically around 2300. Each file will have 4 different data sets with equal structure. Thus, I will quickly achieve a storage problem. My two questions:

1. Is there any reason not the split the 4 different data sets, and just save as `4x20x1500xN`instead? I would prefer having them split, since it is different signal modalities, but if there is any computational/compression advantage to not having them separated, I will join them.
2. Using Matlab's built-in compression, I set `deflate=9` (and `DataType=single`). However, I have now realized that using `deflate` multiplies my computational time with 5. I realize this could have something to do with my `ChunkSize`, which I just put to `20x1500x5` - without any reasoning behind it. Is there a strategic way to optimize computational load w.r.t. deflation and compression time?

Thank you.

Comment: Compare the performance and file size you got with `save('example.mat','yourdata','-v7.3')`. It writes a gip compressed HDF5, to my experience with a good compromise between speed and compression. Realising that I stopped using the hdf5 libraries directly.

Comment: @Daniel The thing is that I am going to write to this file using a parfor loop, which is why I chose to use H5.

Comment: There is no reason not to use save in that context: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/135285-how-do-i-use-save-with-a-parfor-loop-using-parallel-computing-toolbox

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for that.

Comment: Just for the record: I would still like my original question answered. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- Splitting or merging? It won't make a difference in the compression procedure, since it is performed in blocks.

2- Your choice of chunkshape seems, indeed, bad. Chunksize determines the shape and size of each block that will be compressed independently. The bad is that each chunk is of 600 kB, that is much larger than the L2 cache, so your CPU is likely twiddling its fingers, waiting for data to come in. Depending on the nature of your data and the usage pattern you will use the most (read the whole array at once, random reads, sequential reads...) you may want to target the L1 or L2 sizes, or something in between. [Here](http://www.pytables.org/usersguide/optimization.html) are some experiments done with a Python library that may serve you as a guide.

Once you have selected your chunksize (how many bytes will your compression blocks have), you have to choose a chunkshape. I'd recommend the shape that most closely fits your reading pattern, if you are doing partial reads, or filling in in a fastest-axis-first if you want to read the whole array at once. In your case, this will be something like `1x1500x10`, I think (second axis being the fastest, last one the second fastest, and fist the slowest, change if I am mistaken).

Lastly, keep in mind that the details are quite dependant on the specific machine you run it: the CPU, the quality and load of the hard drive or SSD, speed of RAM... so the fine tuning will always require some experimentation.

Comment: Thank you very much for an enlightening post. Definitely usable.